# Page loading blocks by remote javascript

Tags: javascript

I am loading external javascript on my site through:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.write("<script src='http://remoteserver/banner.php?id=10&amp;type=image&amp;num=3&amp;width=200'><\/script>");
</script>
```

Everything was fine, but today was a big timeout from the remote server and page loading on site was blocking.

Is there possibility to load javascript asynchronous or to load it after page loads?
I don't want page load interruption while remote server not working.

I know there are tag async in HTML5, but it's not working, i think because this script is more complex than javascript (its ending with ".php").
Also i know it's better to put javascript files before /body tag to prevent this problem, but it's not the best solution.

Do you know other solutions?

Comment: You could write this tag into the page on a 'completion' event over the containing page. That way, the content has loaded first and even if the remote server blocks, it is not blocking anything on the page.

Comment: "Also i know it's better to put javascript files before /body tag to prevent this problem, but it's not the best solution." citation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by creating DOM nodes.

```
<script>
    var scriptEl = document.createElement("script"); //Create a new "script" element.
    scriptEl.src = "http://remoteserver/banner.php?id=10&amp;type=image&amp;num=3&amp;width=200";
    // ^ Set the source to whatever is needed.
    document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
    // Append the script element at the bottom of the body.
</script>
```

Comment: @metadings: Right, corrected. Next time, feel free to suggest an edit and I'll accept it. You'll get 2 rep out of it too :P

Comment: Script tag injection works, I think adding the `defer` attribute to the script tag might be a simpler and easier approach in this case.

Answer (score 3):

**Sync script blocks the parser...**

*Incorrect Method:*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>
```

---

**Async script will not block the rendering of your page:**

*Correct method:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Il4swGfTOSM&t=1607

Comment: That's okay, maybe there was some truth to the other post. I listened to your criticisms and hopefully this is closer to answering the question. At least I have it for my own reference.